# How do you launch Google Play and point to a specific app from an NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc

I have an app which I have uploaded to the Google Play store.  How do I program an NFC (Near Field Communication) tag so that when the tag is "scanned" it launches Google Play for my app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the http://play.google.com website and search for your app, click on it and note the URL.

Then, on your Android phone, use a tool like NFC Tools and "write" a task (NOTE: TASK) to your tag. Select "Add a Task" -> "Applications" -> "URL / URI". Enter the URL exactly as it appears from the Google Play website (i.e. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp), click "OK" and then "Write" to your NFC tag.  I used the ones here ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MAZMZXM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MAZMZXM)).

Now when users scan that tag, Google Play will open and be directed to your app.